# GO: Slice of unique structs effective reusable implementation

Tags: go

I often need to get rid of duplicates based on arbitrary equals function. 
I need implementation that:

1. is fast and memory effective (does not create map)
2. is reusable and easy to use, think of slice.Sort()  (github.com/bradfitz/slice)
3. it's not required to keep order of the original slice or preserve original slice
4. would be nice to minimize copying

Can this be implemented in go? Why this function is not part of some library I am aware of? 
I was looking e.g. godash (github.com/zillow/godash) implementation uses map and does not allow arbitrary less and equal.

Here is how it should approximately look like. 
Test:

```
import (
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

type bla struct {
    ID string
}

type blas []bla

func (slice blas) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return slice[i].ID < slice[j].ID
}

func (slice blas) EqualID(i, j int) bool {
    return slice[i].ID == slice[j].ID
}

func Test_Unique(t *testing.T) {
    input := []bla{bla{ID: "d"}, bla{ID: "a"}, bla{ID: "b"}, bla{ID: "a"}, bla{ID: "c"}, bla{ID: "c"}}
    expected := []bla{bla{ID: "a"}, bla{ID: "b"}, bla{ID: "c"}, bla{ID: "d"}}
    Unique(input, blas(input).Less, blas(input).EqualID)
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(expected, input) {
        t.Errorf("2: Expected: %v but was %v \n", expected, input)
    }
}
```

What I think will need to be used to implement this:

- Only slices as data structure to keep it simple and for easy sorting.
- Some reflection - the hard part for me! Since I am new to go.

Comment: You may do a binary tree insertion and travel that would be O(nlogn) ,that is good provided it wont take up as much memory as most of the map implementations

Comment: Sure, that's how I do it. Problem is to make it reusable.

Comment: You can use indexes inside the tree and interfaces,check the answer

Answer (score 2):

### Options

- You can sort slice and check for adjacent nodes **creation** = O(n logn),**lookup** = O(log n) , **insertion** = O(n), **deletion** = O(n)
- You can use a Tree and the original slice together **creation** = O(n logn),**lookup** = O(log n) , **insertion** = O(log n), **deletion** = O(log n)

In the tree implementation you may put only the index in tree nodes and evaluation of nodes will be done using the Equal/Less functions defined for the interface.

Here is an example with tree, here is the play [link](https://play.golang.org/p/YiVHkm-9wM)

You have to add more functions to make it usable ,and the code is not cache friendly so you may improve the code for make it cache friendly

### How to use

1. Make the type representing slice implement Setter interface
2. set := NewSet(slice),creates a slice
3. now set.T has only unique values indexes
4. implement more functions to `Set` for other set operations

### Code

```
type Set struct {
    T Tree
    Slice Setter
}

func NewSet(slice Setter) *Set {
    set := new(Set)
    set.T = Tree{nil, 0, nil}
    set.Slice = slice
    for i:=0;i < slice.Len();i++ {
        insert(&set.T, slice, i)
    }
    return set
}

type Setter interface {
    Len() int
    At(int) (interface{},error)
    Less(int, int) bool
    Equal(int, int) bool
}


// A Tree is a binary tree with integer values.
type Tree struct {
    Left  *Tree
    Value int
    Right *Tree
}

func insert(t *Tree, Setter Setter, index int) *Tree {
    if t == nil {
        return &Tree{nil, index, nil}
    }
    if Setter.Equal(t.Value, index) {
        return t
    }

    if Setter.Less(t.Value, index) {
        t.Left = insert(t.Left, Setter, index)
        return t
    }
    t.Right = insert(t.Right, Setter, index)
    return t
}
```

Comment: Interesting. What I had in mind was a binary sort! Btw. Trees are inherently not as easy to cache align as arrays. So this can't be fast.

Comment: `binary sort`  has quadratic complexity O(n^2) .May be you ment  quick sort . I have listed it as an option . But if you go through complexity of the two approaches as i listed in the answer above complexities for operations like lookup, insert,delete etc are O(n) in slice.

Comment: @honzajde Justifiation for using tree is that since we are using only numbers in node node size is very small and assuming cache size of even 1mb you could hold  174762 nodes Tree,approx 17 is depth.

Comment: Yes, I meant to sort and then remove duplicates as you mention in the front, not a binary sort;). Thanks for some estimates. Fort the tree impl. I have these concerns compared to slices impl.: recursion, many allocations, (maybe) garbage collecting a tree!? Not sure how relevant these can be. For practicality I need a slice to pass to next function...  Easy to add to your code, also to remove channels. This might be well the impl I asked for. I think this tree would leed to extremely bad performance for large sizes over L2 cache - there quicksort must have better locality.

Comment: @honzajde Perfect, if you need to remove duplicate just once then quicksort would do great

Answer (score 0):

Bloom filter is frequently used for equality test. There is https://github.com/willf/bloom for example, which awarded some stars on github. This particular implementation uses murmur3 for hashing and bitset for filter, so can be more efficient than map.

Comment: map is not needed, nor is bloom filter